# How to change row to column using pivot in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Input table

product_id  url                             key    value
1231201     http://sample.com/1231201.html  col1    2
1231201     http://sample.com/1231201.html  col2    10
1231201     http://sample.com/1231201.html  col3    3
```

I have been using below mentioned pivot Query :

```
SELECT   product_id,url,col1,col2,col3
FROM   [dbo].[table] 
PIVOT
(
       max(value)
       FOR [key] IN ([col1],[col2],[col3])
) AS P
```

I have got output is mentioned below

```
product_id  url                             col1    col2    col3
1231201     http://sample.com/1231201.html  NULL    2       NULL
1231201     http://sample.com/1231201.html  10      NULL    NULL
1231201     http://sample.com/1231201.html  NULL    NULL    3
```

My Expected output :

```
product_id  url                             col1  col2 col3
1231201     http://sample.com/1231201.html  10     2    3
```

can you please help?

Comment: Are you really using the query you showed us? Because it will show your expected output

Comment: are you sure the url is always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have additional fields in your table (i.e. ID)

Use a sub-query to **isolate/limit** your fields to the desired PIVOT

```
select product_id,url,col1,col2,col3
From (Select product_id,url,[key],value from [dbo].[table] ) a
pivot (max(value) for [key] in ([col1],[col2],[col3])) as p
```

Returns

```
product_id  url                             col1    col2    col3
1231201     http://sample.com/1231201.html  2       10      3
```

Comment: @Antony Happy it helped.  Been bit by that dog before  :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some other column in your table that has unique value for these rows.

You can select the columns you need to pivot in a subquery and then apply pivot.

Try this:

```
select product_id,
    url,
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
from (
    select product_id,
        url,
        [key],
        value
    from [dbo].[table]
    ) t
PIVOT(max(value) for [key] in ([col1], [col2], [col3])) as P
```

#### Demo:

```
with t(id, product_id , url ,[key] ,value) as (
select 1, 1231201 ,'http://sample.com/1231201.html',  'col1',   2  union all
select 2, 1231201 ,'http://sample.com/1231201.html',  'col2',   10 union all
select 3, 1231201 ,'http://sample.com/1231201.html',  'col3',   3 
)
select product_id,
    url,
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
from (
    select product_id,
        url,
        [key],
        value
    from t
    ) t
PIVOT(max(value) for [key] in ([col1], [col2], [col3])) as P
```

I get:

```
1231201 http://sample.com/1231201.html  2   10  3
```

For your query:

```
with t(id, product_id , url ,[key] ,value) as (
select 1, 1231201 ,'http://sample.com/1231201.html',  'col1',   2  union all
select 2, 1231201 ,'http://sample.com/1231201.html',  'col2',   10 union all
select 3, 1231201 ,'http://sample.com/1231201.html',  'col3',   3 
)
select product_id,
    url,
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
from t
PIVOT(max(value) for [key] in ([col1], [col2], [col3])) as P
```

I get:

```
1231201 http://sample.com/1231201.html  2   NULL    NULL
1231201 http://sample.com/1231201.html  NULL    10  NULL
1231201 http://sample.com/1231201.html  NULL    NULL    3
```